# Rebuild MSI if only updated files

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a setup where I'm building the MSI along with a CAB containing all the files. I also need to build different MSIs for different languages. I have already built all of them and they all share the same CAB file.

Recently I updated a couple of files and rebuilt one of the MSIs (which also rebuilt the CAB file).

**Do I need to rebuild every MSI as well?**

Comment: Why don't you build a [multi-lingual MSI](https://www.hass.de/content/how-create-msi-packages-multilingual-user-interface-mui)?

Comment: @zett42 We'd rather have single language MSIs. Business preferences, I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because the MSI contains details about the files that will be installed, such as file size, version, file hash. These need to match with the files being installed.

Comment: It makes sense. But is there any documentation that supports that? I've been trying to find some, but with no success.

Comment: @JuanFerrer If you look at the [File table reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368596(v=vs.85).aspx), you can see that it stores many informations about the files. File hashes are stored in the [MsiFileHash table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372406(v=vs.85).aspx) (usually only for unversioned files).

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the resources. So, definitely, need to rebuild since the UID was modified when the file was changed.